# How to validate email and password in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor I want to know how to check or put condition for validating email inputs and password. I am unable to put the condition to check whether the password and email is valid with regular expression thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the credentials by filling the inputs then expect to get another page or to hide a modal (depend on your app). Or you can fill with wrong credentials then expect to view an error message (like "incorrect user/password").

This kind of testing isn't secure, but you can be sure that the app is functionally.

Comment: thnks, I tried this earlier with single values but i want to validate email and password with multiple values.